# MEAN io module not working properly

Tags: mean-stack, mean, mean.io

I am new in mean stack and i am creating module.

My module is not working properly,some time it works and some time not.
I dont understand what i am doing wrong.

> packages/custom/settings/public/routes/settings.js

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('mean.settings').config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {

    // states for my app
    $stateProvider
      .state('all settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: '/settings/views/list.html',        
      });
  }
]);
```

> packages/custom/settings/public/controllers/settings.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.settings').controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Settings',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Settings) {
    $scope.global = Global;       

    $scope.find = function() {
      Settings.query(function(settings) {
        $scope.settings = settings;
      });
    };

  }
]);
```

> packages/custom/settings/public/views/list.html

```
<section data-ng-controller="SettingsController" data-ng-init="find()">
  <ul class="settings unstyled">
    <li data-ng-repeat="setting in settings">
      Hello
      <div>{{setting.Name}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1 data-ng-hide="!settings || settings.length">No settings yet. <br> Why don't you <a href="/settings/create">Create One</a>?</h1>
</section>
```